# let promise wait a couple of seconds before return

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I'm having a function returning a promise. In this function, we call a third party vender to send some push notification through their server.

it looks like

```
apiGetLoggedInUser.then(
  user => {
    return sendMessage(user.name);
  }
)
```

However the thing is we decided to wait for 3 seconds before we really call this sendMessage function. However we'd prefer not to change sendMessage since it's provided.

I'm wondering how to really do the "wait" part in this scenario since promise is used to remove "sync" operations.

Am I understanding correctly? What shall I do?

Comment: you should do that on promise creation, and return the promise later

Comment: Did you try using `setTimeout` ? if you consider that approach, you might need a callback to handle the promise return by `sendMessage` after 3s.

Answer (score 44):

The short version:

```
function wait(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

Example:

```
async function myFunc(user) {
  await wait(3000);

  sendMessage(user.name);
}
```

Comment: one-liner:
 const wait = ms=>new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r,ms));

Answer (score 24):

Insert another promise in the chain which delays the next one:

```
apiGetLoggedInUser
    .then(user => {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(user), 3000));
    })
    .then(user => sendMessage(user.name))
```

Comment: Follow up question: is this gonna block the main loop? if so is there any way to mitigate? Thanks @deceze

Comment: No, this does not block.

Comment: The reason it doesn't block is because Promises work with await & async from memory.

Answer (score 7):

A different approach - useful if you want to do this sort of thing in many places

This bit is done once

```
Promise.prototype.thenWait = function thenWait(time) {
    return this.then(result => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time, result)));
};
```

Then you can use it, like this usage for your example, anywhere

```
apiGetLoggedInUser.thenWait(3000).then(user => sendMessage(user.name));
```

Answer (score 2):

Create new promise which will call `sendMessage` after a timeout.

```
apiGetLoggedInUser.then(
  user => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          sendMessage(user.name).then(resolve, reject);
       }, 3000)
    });
  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify-wait

```
import wait, { DURATION_UNIT } from "promisify-wait";

# wait 1000 milliseconds
await wait(1000) #Default in millisecond

# wait 10 seconds
await wait(10, DURATION_UNIT.SECOND)

# wait 1 minute 
await wait(1, DURATION_UNIT.MINUTE)
```

Comment: Using some external library is definitelly NOT "simply". You should avoid doing this, instead use native js code.