# How to slow down a single request / API endpoint for development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

EDIT: I am asking to slow down a SINGLE api call. Not the whole network. And I can't change the actual response time server side.

I am working in React. One component makes use of an API endpoint that sometimes takes very long. Every time that happens we allow the user to save, due to a bug.

I want to know how to slow down just that one API call, in order to create that particular situation.

So, I have for example

```
setLoading(true)
const templates = await getTemplates(dispatch)
setLoading(false)
```

in one component.

I would like to know what options I have to simulate that API response taking n seconds. No matter if doing that by code, tooling, etc..

Comment: You could achieve this by throttling your connections if i am not mistaken using the network tab in your chrome dev tools.

Comment: Chrome Dev Tools has throttling of network connections: https://umaar.com/dev-tips/66-network-throttling-profiles/

Comment: I need the rest of the api calls to respond normally.

Comment: if you are using axios, something like axios(blahblah).then(res => {await sleep(2000); ....})

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout()` on the server to delay sending the response, or on the client before resolving the promise.

---

**EDIT:** The code depends on your particular implementation/tools. Please share a snippet from your client-side function which calls the API, or the handler on the server.

Nevertheless, here's an example based on your snippet and JS's `Promise`/`await` combo:

```js
setLoading(true)
const templates = await getTemplates(dispatch)
const delay = 1000;
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
setLoading(false);
```

**Other example: `node.js` server**

```js
app.get('/api/whatever', (request, response) => {
  const data = getDataFromDatabase():
  const delay = 1000;
  setTimeout(function() {
    response.end(data);
  }, delay);
})
```

Comment: Code, please (:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const call = (dati) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => { resolve(dati); }, 1000);
    })
```

or you can see here: [let promise wait a couple of seconds before return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529476/let-promise-wait-a-couple-of-seconds-before-return)