# Understanding javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

[Edit: this is a question about Promises, not setTimeout.  Please don't close it without actually reading the question]

I'm trying to understand Promises.  From what I've read and understood (which is obviously incomplete or wrong), the following should wait 3 seconds, append "in foo", then append "in bar".

However, "in bar" is first, followed by a 3 second wait, followed by "in foo".

I could use a shove in the right direction on this.

```js
function promiseTest() {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(foo, 3000);
  });
  promise.then(foo).then(bar());
}

function foo() {
  jQuery('#demo').append("<li>in foo</li>");
}

function bar() {
  jQuery('#demo').append("<li>in bar</li>");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id='demo'></ul>
  <button onclick='promiseTest()'>click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529476/let-promise-wait-a-couple-of-seconds-before-return does this help?

Comment: I think I'd have to agree with the OP, without some explanation I don't see how this duplicate applies..

Comment: Actually no, the duplicate does apply, it's just misleading because `setTimeout` is in the dupe title and that's not the problem code here. You're calling `bar()` in the `.then`, not passing it as a callback.

Comment: `promise.then(foo).then(bar);`

Comment: Your promise also never resolves, so none of this code `.then(foo).then(bar);` is actually ran.

Comment: Voted to reopen. The linked question doesn't seem directly relevant here. The answer here is related to resolving the promise, not the way they're calling `setTimeout`. I know there are a few issues here with `setTimeout(foo, 3000)` and `.then(foo)` and `.then(bar())`, but these multiple issues can be addressed in an answer, not a seemingly not-quite-related question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In JavaScript, does it make a difference if I call a function with parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246928/in-javascript-does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-call-a-function-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 2):

Since this was reopened, and there multiple issues outside of the initial source of confusion, let me try to explain the problems.

#### 1. Syntax for passing a callback

Executing a callback function is the responsibility of the function you pass it to. So in the case of `setTimeout`, you expect that after 3 seconds *it* will call the function you pass it.

```
const foo = () => console.log('foo');
setTimeout(foo, 3000);
// OR
setTimeout(() => console.log('foo'), 3000);
```

In both scenarios, you are passing a function, but never calling it yourself.

`promise.then(foo).then(bar())` is a problem because you are calling `bar`, not passing it.

#### 2. Unresolved promises

`promise` never completes, because you never called `resolve` or `reject`. This means, neither `.then` actually executes.

You were deceived into thinking they were because of the bug with `bar()`.

#### Final solution

In order to accomplish what you want, you need to resolve the promise. But you need to do so *after* `foo` is called. The best way to do this may be to create an anonymous function for the `setTimeout` callback that calls both `foo` and `resolve`.

See below:

```js
function promiseTest() {
  let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      foo();
      resolve();
    }, 3000);
  });
  promise.then(bar);
}

function foo() {
  jQuery('#demo').append("<li>in foo</li>");
}

function bar() {
  jQuery('#demo').append("<li>in bar</li>");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id='demo'></ul>
  <button onclick='promiseTest()'>click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't understand "resolve()", and was confused between "bar" and "bar()".  MUCH thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The argument you're supposed to pass to `then()` needs to be a function, you are not passing the function `bar`, you are passing the *result* of calling the function `bar`.

Remove the parenthesis to refer to the function instead of the result of calling it.

Comment: oh, if that were the only problem with that code :p